# Is there a way to check if a field has changed in a specific row without writing listeners for each?

Tags: java, listener

I have a dialog that allows the user to add rows of fields dynamically. Each row consists of 8 fields (combo boxes and formatted text fields) plus a button that when clicked adds a new row of empty fields. Is there an easy way to detect if any field in a particular row has been modified? I don't want to have to create a listener for each and every field in each and every row but I don't see any other way to do it. If that is the only way is there some limit I may hit with too many listeners? TIA.

Comment: Could you post the code you have so far, or a [mcve] ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I haven't really written listeners, just the code that creates the rows of fields. Are you asking for the incomplete class that manages the dialog?

Comment: You could create a model class that has a collection of elements with each element representing a row. Some /all of the fields in each row should change when the model changes. If you want to know which field in which row changed due to the model change, you could write a state change listener for the model. Or you could write a single listener that listens to text/combo field's events.

Comment: @WtRiker : Yes please post what you have so far .

Comment: svasa: Thanks for the suggestion. I have not use model classes and did not know about them. It sounds like that may make my job much easier but I'll need to research that some.

Comment: Berger: Thanks but let me look into svasa's suggestion first. I may throw away my code and start over.

Comment: `Yes please post what you have so far` - why? This is a design question asking for a better way than creating listeners for every component. People use the "post an mcve too frequently".

Comment: @camickr : We don't even know what a row is supposed to be here. For instance, is there a `JTable` ? A minimal piece of code would help understanding what we are talking about , which is frequently better than not knowing.

Comment: The code is quite large but I will post it. However, I need some advice on how to do that. If I copy and paste my code using the {} formatting feature of this list it does come out right. The 4 spaces are not maintained when I paste. How do I paste and maintain the 4 spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out if a control's content has been altered you need to add a Listener. Period.

You can make your life easier by extending each of the components you use to a custom component that either implements its own event (But then always the same event, like "ContentChanged"), or takes a Java 8 Consumer function that is called whenever the content changes.
Like

```
protected void textChanged( String changedText ) {
    // Collect all changes here
}

JTextField textField = new MyTextField( text -> textChanged( text ) );

private class MyTextField extends JTextField {
    private final Consumer<String> textChangedConsumer;

    public MyTextField( Consumer<String> textChangedConsumer ) {
        super();
        this.textChangedConsumer = textChangedConsumer;

        getDocument().addDocumentListener( new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate( DocumentEvent e ) {
                textChangedConsumer.accept( getText() );
            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate( DocumentEvent e ) {
                textChangedConsumer.accept( getText() );
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate( DocumentEvent e ) {
                textChangedConsumer.accept( getText() );
            }
        } );
    }
}
```

You use this class every time you need a text field and have one common method to collect the changes. Do the same likewise for JComboBoxes and so on. Let all of them point to your textChanged method.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. I've not extended a class myself before so it looks like a good opportunity to learn. Thanks.